# Save current tab link inside of chrome extension popup window

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, popup, popupwindow

I am trying to create a chrome extension that, when clicked, a popup-window opens and inside of that window is a button. When the button is clicked, the  of the popup-window should update to the current-tab's link.

[See this picture, this is my window popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dk3kW.png)

However, when I click the button, nothing works...
Here is what I have so far:

manifest.json:

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Save",

  "description": "Save tab link.",

  "version": "0.1",

  "browser_action": {

    "default_icon": "/img/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "See your saved websites!"
      },

     "permissions":  [
       "tabs"
       ]
}
```

popup.html:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Your articles</title>
    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div">No content yet! Click the button to add the link of the current website!</div>
    <br/>
    <button id="button">Add link!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Finally, popup.js:

```js
// event listener for the button inside popup window
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var button = document.getElementById('button');
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        addURL();
    });
});

// add the URL inside the popup-window's <div> 
function addURL() {
// store info in the the queryInfo object as per: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query
    var queryInfo = {
    currentWindow: true,
    active: true
    };
    
    chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function(tabs) {
    // tabs is an array so fetch the first (and only) object-elemnt in tab
    // put URL propery of tab in another variable as per: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab
    var url = tabs[0].url;
    
    // put the content into the popup-window's <div>
    document.getElementById("div").innerHTML(url);
    });
}
```

I hope that someone could help me out there :)

Comment: As @HaibaraAi mentioned: Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, adding additional information, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question to change it into a different question which results in invalidating an Answer, is against policy on Stack Overflow. Your edit here did so. The policy is that other users should proactively revert such changes. I have done so here. You *are encouraged to [ask a new Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)*, perhaps with a link to this one for additional context. We want to help, but your new issue needs to be a new Question.

Comment: You can see the revisions, and get the source text that was in your edit [at this link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41280221/revisions).

Comment: @Makyen, I honestly didn't think about it that way. Ofcourse I didn't want her answer to become invalid. I have apologized to HaibaraAi and asked how to return it to the previous state because I had no intentions on going against the policy. I'm sorry for the fuss I created, I promise I won't do that anymore next time.

Comment: I think you handled the it reasonably. You did something you did not know you weren't supposed to do. Once you were informed that was the case, you clearly accepted it and were/are willing to go with what the consensus is for the policy. I should have acknowledged this in an earlier comment. I'm sorry I didn't. Mostly, my first comment tried to say why I went ahead and reverted the edit rather than explaining how you could do so, while attempting to get across the message that the reversion was not a rejection of your new question. With the limited length of comments, some portions were lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML(url);
```

with

```
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = url;
```

Comment: Allright thank you very much! I didn't see this small fault at all!

Comment: Could you maybe look at the edited version to?

Comment: @Kobrajunior, You shouldn't remove previous post, that will cause my answer become meaningless. For additional asks, you should raise another question with descriptions.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, How can I return the previous post back? I will re-edit the old post if it isn't possible to "return" to previous post.